# Combobox value changes event in Data GridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, desktop-application

I have a DataGridView that contains 2 columns, the first is a combo box and the second also is combobox in windows app.

If the user changes the combobox, I need to update the second combo box in the third column appropriately, but my problem is how to do this?
i have added two combobox using the below technique

```
 DataTable Pdt = new DataTable();
            Pdt = objProductCategory.SelectAll();
            BindingSource ps = new BindingSource();
            ps.DataSource = Pdt;
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ProductCatColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            ProductCatColumn.DataSource = ps;
            ProductCatColumn.HeaderText = "Product Category";
            ProductCatColumn.Name = "ProductCatColumn";
            ProductCatColumn.ValueMember = "ProductCatId";
            ProductCatColumn.DisplayMember = "CatName";
            gvSale.Columns.Add(ProductCatColumn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a class that inherits `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`.

Then overwrite any event method you need, for example `OnKeyUp` for direct validation on key stroke.

[DataGridViewComboBoxCell Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood the question correctly, but if so, then you could solve your problem maybe so

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn
    Header="FirstColumn"
    ItemsSource="{Binding FirstItemsSource}"
    SelectedValuePath="{Binding FirstSelectedValuePath}"
    DisplayMemberPath="{Binding FirstDisplayMemberPath}"
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding FirstSelectedValue}"/>
<DataGridComboBoxColumn
    Header="SecondColumn"
    ItemsSource="{Binding SecondItemsSource}"
    SelectedValuePath="{Binding SecondSelectedValuePath}"
    DisplayMemberPath="{Binding SecondDisplayMemberPath}"
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding SecondSelectedValue}"/>
```

In your DataContext (code-behind, or ViewModel), you implement corresponding properties:

```
public IList<YourType> FirstItemsSource
{
    get
    {
        return this.firstItemsSource;
    }
    set
    {
        this.firstItemsSource = value;
    }
}

public YourType SecondSelectedValue
{
    get
    {
        return this.secondSelectedValue;
    }
    set
    {
        this.secondSelectedValue = value;

        // here you can set the FirstItemsSource
        this.FirstItemsSource = this.RefreshFirstItemsSource();
    }
}
```

I hope I have understood you correctly, and that this solution helps you further;-)